# SailsJS RESTful Json API searching

Tags: json, api, mongodb, rest, sails.js

I'm beginning with Sails, I'm trying to implement the RESTful Json API document creation and searching.

I have documents like this:

```
[
  {
    "players": [
      {
        "name": "jonathan"
      },
      {
        "name": "nicolas"      
      }
    ],
    "createdAt": "2013-11-05T12:35:41.578Z",
    "updatedAt": "2013-11-05T12:35:41.578Z",
    "id": "5278e61ddbc01cd206000003"
  },
  {
    "players": [
      {
        "name": "eddy"
      },
      {
        "name": "jonathan"
      }
    ],
    "createdAt": "2013-11-05T12:37:52.526Z",
    "updatedAt": "2013-11-05T12:37:52.526Z",
    "id": "5278e6a0dbc01cd206000004"
  }
]
```

Now I would like to search through a POST Json request the documents that, for example, have a player named `nicolas`. I'm not sure how to do it.

I thought about this but no luck:

```
{
  'where':{
    'players.name':'nicolas'
  }
}
```

I'm using sails-mongo adapter by the way.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are looking for the ['Query Language'](http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/concepts/ORM/Querylanguage.html) section in the 'Models and ORM' portion of the SailsJS documentation and the ['Working with Queries'](http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/reference/waterline/queries) section of the Waterline docs may be helpful, too.

Note: Don't let older tutorials like https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HozWtywQNMo confuse you. I believe the query syntax has changed a bit. So it might be worth reading the migration guide, as well.

Here's an example:

```
    User.find({id: req.params['id'], limit: 1})
    .then(function foundUser(user){
        if(!user) return next();
        res.view({
            user: user[0]
        });
    })
    .catch(function(err){
        if(err) return next(err);
    });
```

or:

```
    User.findOne({id: req.params['id']})
    .exec(function foundUser(err, user){
        if(err) return next(err);
        if(!user) return next();
        res.view({
            user: user
        });
    });
```

Happy sailing.